# Listing or Working With a Range in the Shell

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

Is there any way I can target a range of a-c* in one go?

For example, instead of doing this individually;

```
/home/a*
/home/b*
/home/c*
```

I've tried testing with `ls`, but not sure if it's working right.

```
ls /home/[a-c]*
```

Comment: `ls /home/[a-c]*` seems to work ok. I've added an alternate way of expanding a sequence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ls /home/{a..c}*
```

(This is some extra text to meet the minimum body length.)

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you want a non-contiguous list:
`ls /home/[aceg]*`
will list /home/a*, /home/c*, /home/e*, /home/g*